# I want to verify text in HTML5 form validation

Tags: html, forms, validation

I want to verify text in HTML5 form validation. For example, when I fill in a field which should take email address only but when user inputs letters instead, the error message shows up, how can I verify that error message? I have been struggling with this for a very long time and your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Show us a little bit of your code, so we can improve or correct it...

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML5 there are new input type available i.e. email, tel ... By typing something like this in your form:
`<input type="email" required />`
you get an email field that is validaded through HTML5. It also has the advantage that, when your page is used on a mobile device the keyboard changes i.e. when you have a *tel* field the keyboard layout changes to a numbers-only keyboard.

Alternatively you can use a pattern to check whether an email address is valid. 
`<input pattern="\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@ (?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])\z"/>` (no guarantee that this is correct

More information on different input types available since HTML5:

http://www.wufoo.com/html5/

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html

http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

If you want to make absolutely sure that your email is valid I don't think there's a way around using javascript i.e. to check if a country code is actually valid.